# Error in applying array filter in array with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

Currently I am working on an JavaScript exercise.

The aim of the exercise is to compare the array which formed with different objects. there are 2 parameters for the function: The collection is the main array, and the source is the comparison criteria. Only the objects in main array which contains the key and same properties as source array would be returned.

The outcome should be as follows:

```
whatIsInAName(
  [{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }],
  { last: "Capulet" }
) // should return [{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }].

whatIsInAName(
  [{ "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }],
  { "apple": 1 }
) // should return [{ "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }]

whatIsInAName(
  [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }],
  { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }
) // should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }]

whatIsInAName(
  [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }],
  { "apple": 1, "cookie": 2 }
) // should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }]

whatIsInAName(
  [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }, { "bat":2 }],
  { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }
) // should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie":2 }]

whatIsInAName(
  [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}],
  {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3}
) // should return []
```

To tackle this, I use the array filter function and aim to select the object which matches the criteria and return as new array. The code is as follows:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var arr = [];
  var key = Object.keys(source)

  return collection.filter(function(x){
    for(var y = 0; y < key.length; y++){
      if(x.hasOwnProperty(key[y]) && x[key[y]] == source[key[y]]){
        return true;
      }
    }
  return true;
  }) 

}

whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

However, when I test the condition in the console, it returns the following:

[{…}, {…}, {…}]

And at the same time, I saw that there is an similar answer. But the difference is, it use the negative selections which return false when there is sth not matched like this:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var srcKeys = Object.keys(source);

  return collection.filter(function (obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < srcKeys.length; i++) {
      if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(srcKeys[i]) || obj[srcKeys[i]] !== source[srcKeys[i]]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
}

// test here
whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" });
```

This time it works.

So what I want to know is, what is my error on the first script? 
And if I still want to use the positive criteria i.e only return cases which match the both criteria, how can I make it?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code doesn't work because you are returning `true` as soon as a property matches the criteria. It doesn't proceed with checking the rest of the keys.

For example imaging `x` is `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` and `source` is `{ a: 1, b: 1}`. Your original code checks the property `a`, it matches, so `true` is returned from `filter`. It doesn't proceed to check if `b` matches or not (because `return` terminates the function immediately).

The second code example does exactly the opposite, it stops checking the properties once it finds one that doesn't match (if a property doesn't match then checking the rest will be redundant).

**Original code:** searches for a property that matches the criteria. If one is found, `true` is returned, if none found, `false` is returned. This code fails only if all keys fail to match, succeeds if at least one key matches.

**Second code:** searches for a property that doesn't match. If one is found, `false` is returned, if none found, `true` is returned. This code fails if at least one key fails to match, succeeds if all keys match.

Comment: hi ibrahim, this is simply great and really helpful!
And a question: As I know that filter is going to scan all elements in the array. Before I always understand that, in this case it will just scan through all the objects in the array, but the filter will scan through the key and the properties in every object indeed?

Comment: @PakHangLeung `filter` does scan through the whole array, but it's your function that should scan through the objects. `filter` loops over the array and call the function you privide to it on each object from the array, it then see if that function call yields `true` or `false` to decide whether the object should be included. `filter` doesn't know what the function does and doesn't care, it only cares about its return value. In your original code, the function you pass to `filter` doesn't do its job, it just check if at least one key (of the passed in object) matches to return `true`.

Answer (score 3):

In your original function that is not working you are always returning `true` from the `filter` callback, so nothing gets filtered out.

But, you should also be able to just filter and use `every` with `Object.keys` of the search object:

```js
function whatIsInAName(arr, search_obj) {
     return arr.filter(obj => Object.keys(search_obj)
           .every(key => obj[key] === search_obj[key]))
}


console.log(whatIsInAName([{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], { last: "Capulet" }))
 // [{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }].

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }], { "apple": 1 }))
// [{ "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }]

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }))
// [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }]

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "cookie": 2 }))
//  [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }]

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }, { "bat":2 }], { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }))
// [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie":2 }]

console.log(whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3}))
// []
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds, well done! BTW the `obj[key] &&` is totally unecessary and it may cause problems if the property is `0`, `false`, ... etc: `whatIsInAName([{"a": 0}, {"a": 0, "b": 1}], {"a": 0})`